# How can I fix AMD Radeon 5600 XT windows 31 error?

Tags: windows, gpu, amd

I have a weird issue with my graphics card. Recently it started crashing and giving a windows 31 error in my device manager.

Uninstalling the driver from the device manager and using AMD Software installer fixes it for a few hours. The weird thing is that I don't have to complete the AMD Software installer. The graphics card is already fixed when I the AMD Software installer is still scanning my PC. My graphics card also shows up again in my device manager like nothing happened. Even though I uninstalled it moments ago.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the issue and how I could fix this permanently?